# Convert string representation of binary number to int in C#

Tags: c#, string, binary, type-conversion

I have a string of eight 1s and 0s with spaces in between, something like "1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0", that I want converted in to an int. Is there a simple way to do this? I feel like some kind of linq parsing would do it, but I don't even know what to do with the characters once I find them.

Comment: Just to clarify, the string `1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0` should be parsed as two, four bit values: `1001` and `1010`.  Then converted to hex.  Correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need any LINQ.
`Convert.ToInt*()` takes an optional `fromBase` parameter, which must be 2, 8, 10, or 16.

```
Convert.ToInt32("1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0".Replace(" ", ""), 2)
```

Comment: Well that makes this a very simple problem then hah. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @SLaks's answer (but only for parsing Hex) is

```
Int32.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

There's no equivalent for binary, though, so his is a better general-purpose answer.

Comment: I was mistaken. Removed earlier comment.