# Better way to convert a binary format string(0 and 1) to byte[]?

Tags: c#, binary, asciiencoding

I have write this, is a good one?

```
byte[] ConvertToBytes(string b)
    {
        BitArray bits = new BitArray(b.ToList().ConvertAll<bool>(x => x == '1').ToArray());

        byte[] ret = new byte[bits.Length];
        bits.CopyTo(ret, 0);

        return ret;
    }
```

(the array must be readable as an ascii string)

Comment: Efficient wise ? I can write better. Also you're not checking for null string b (throwing ArgumentNullException ...)

Comment: tnw, I put it in linqpad and the intellisense didn't pick up on it, but it compiled and ran!

Comment: tnw, this actually work for me lol

Comment: @tnw http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of binary number to int in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264203/convert-string-representation-of-binary-number-to-int-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Sam Are you set on using `byte[]`? Personally I prefer dealing with binary numbers as integers (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19709466/1185053))

Answer (score 2):

```
string array = "1010101";
byte[] sequence = array.Select(c => Convert.ToByte(c.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Or

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(array);
```

Comment: ☺ this is what i get for all chars, i think is not right for ascii format

Comment: Shorter form: array.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

You may be better off not using `byte[]` but actually just storing the binary number as an integer:

```
Convert.ToInt32("1011", 2) // returns 11
```

And the other way round:

```
Convert.ToString(11, 2) // returns "1011"
```

And if you need to get the `nth` bit across (from right):

```
public int GetNthBit(int binary, int n)
{
    return (binary >> n) % 2;
}
```

Usage:

```
GetNthBit(11, 2) // returns 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a efficient way, thought it must not be that hard to implement.

I am assuming that the string will well formed that it is a binary representation in string format.

```
private static byte[] BinStringToBytes(string binary)
{
    //make sure the string length is multiple of 32, if not pad it with zeroes
    var neededZeros = 32 - (binary.Length % 32);

    if (neededZeros > 0)
        binary = string.Concat(new string('0', neededZeros), binary);

    var blocks = binary.Length / 32;

    var binbytes = new byte[blocks * 4];

    for (var i = 0; i < blocks; i++)
    {
        var numstr = binary.Substring(i * 32, 32);
        var num = Convert.ToUInt32(numstr, 2);
        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
        Array.Copy(bytes, 0, binbytes, i * 4, 4);
    }

    return binbytes;
}
```

Comment: A bit long and gives me a deformed string, for example `loool` in binary become `l   looo` on decoding. I was searching for something like a direct decoding method, but there isn't so i continue to use my own, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mehrdad has [***a good answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp) to your question. The code:

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: i get the same binary string just with a space between the numbers, like this `0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible I misunderstand the question, but:

```
public byte[] BitStringToAsciiArray(string bits)
{
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bits);
}
```

However, it doesn't give any error if any of the characters in the input string are something other than `'0'` or `'1'`.

But otherwise it does return an array of bytes each which is 48 for a `'0'` in the input string and 49 for a `'1'` in the input string. These are the ASCII codes for `'0'` and `'1'` respectively.

Comment: The function must convert the binary format to byte[], not just the string, else i get the same one decoding the bytes

Comment: @Sam What binary format? The input is a string. Can you provide a sample input string? From your question, one would assume that it would look like: "1010111010110" kind of thing. And if the output array must be readable as an ASCII string, it can consist only of bytes with the values 48 or 49.

Answer (score 0):

Append all the chars into a long as below:

```
var l = 0L;
foreach (var c in s)
{
    l <<= 1;
    l += c;
}
var b = BitConverter.GetBytes(l);
```