# String of bits to Unicode

Tags: c#, string, unicode, bit

I have a string of bits, like this `string str = "0111001101101000"` It's the letters"sh".
 I need to make Unicode letters out of it. I'm doing following:

```
BitArray bn = new BitArray(str.Length); //creating new bitarray
for (int kat = 0; kat < str.Length; kat++)
{
    if (str[kat].ToString() == "0")//adding boolean values into array
    {
        bn[kat] = false;
    }
    else
        bn[kat] = true;
}

byte[] bytes = new byte[bn.Length];//converting to bytes
bn.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
string output = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes); //encoding                          

textBox2.Text = output; // result in textbox
```

But the output text is just complete mess. How to do it right?

Comment: What was the expected result?

Comment: As i said, "It's the letters"sh".", so, i expected letters "sh".
And i'm getting question marks, hieroglyphs, etc.

Comment: What encoding are you using? UTF8 of "sh" gives me "1100111000010110", code here, http://ideone.com/UdvG6r

Comment: You can see what i did wrong in the answer below.

Comment: Essentially your string is UTF8 with the wrong endianess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of binary number to int in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264203/convert-string-representation-of-binary-number-to-int-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Make sure you have the conversion from bits correct first.  Then returning the associated unicode code point should be a separate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your code.

1. First `BitArray` will reverse the bit order - it's easier to use
   `Convert.ToByte`
2. Your input string contains two bytes (one
   per character), but you're using `Encoding.Unicode` to decode it, which
   is UTF16 encoding (two bytes per character), you need to use `Encoding.UTF8`

**Working Code**

```
string str = "0111001101101000";

int numOfBytes = str.Length / 8;
byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
for (int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; ++i)
{
    bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(str.Substring(8 * i, 8), 2);
}

string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

A) Your string is ASCII, not UNICODE: 8 bits per character

B) The most significant bit of every byte is on the left, so the strange math used in bn[...]

C) The commented part is useless because "false" is the default state of a `BitArray`

D) The length of the byte array was wrong. 8 bits == 1 byte! :-)

```
string str = "0111001101101000";

BitArray bn = new BitArray(str.Length); //creating new bitarray

for (int kat = 0; kat < str.Length; kat++) {
    if (str[kat] == '0')//adding boolean values into array
    {
        //bn[(kat / 8 * 8) + 7 - (kat % 8)] = false;
    } else {
        bn[(kat / 8 * 8) + 7 - (kat % 8)] = true;
    }
}

// 8 bits in a byte
byte[] bytes = new byte[bn.Length / 8];//converting to bytes
bn.CopyTo(bytes, 0);

string output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes); //encoding
```

Probably better:

```
string str = "0111001101101000";

byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length / 8];

for (int ix = 0, weight = 128, ix2 = 0; ix < str.Length; ix++) {
    if (str[ix] == '1') {
        bytes[ix2] += (byte)weight;
    }

    weight /= 2;

    // Every 8 bits we "reset" the weight 
    // and increment the ix2
    if (weight == 0) {
        ix2++;
        weight = 128;
    }
}

string output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes); //encoding
```